# Okta with React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, okta

I had a react native app to which i need to integrate OKTA, i have installed following packages for it

> npm install @okta/okta-signin-widget@2.3.0 --save

I added the app in okta development site as OPENID Connect,Application Type :Single Page App (SPA). The problem is after assigning the app in okta site (https://dev-845745-admin.oktapreview.com) to the people, the assigned members are unable to see the app in Dashboard page.

Comment: react-native app or a web app using react?

Comment: react-native app@bennygenel

Comment: The widget you are trying to use is for web apps and most likely it is not going to work with react-native out of the box

Comment: Thanks.can u tell me what type of package should i use and also  if i want to integrate okta login  with my app should i choose OPEN ID Connect or SAML as sign on method

Comment: I don't know anything about OKTA so I can't tell anything. All I know is that it's a web app widget.

Comment: @bennygenel is correct, the widget doesn't work with react-native. Take a look at [this post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-react-native-app-and-authenticate-with-oauth-20) on how to use OAuth instead

Comment: Thanks for ur information @BrianDemers,@bennygenel

Answer (score 2):

You can configure which applications appear on the End-User Dashboard page via your [Okta OpenID Connect Application](https://support.okta.com/help/Documentation/Knowledge_Article/Using-the-App-Integration-Wizard-1111708899#OIDCWizard).

> The **Login Initiated By** setting specifies whether the app is initiated only in the background or whether either the app or Okta can initiate the login. If you select **App Only**, the app is started in the background without an Okta chiclet. If you select **Either Okta or App**, you can utilize an Okta chiclet.

1. Update **Login Initiated By** to **Either Okta or App**
2. Select the **Display application icon to users** checkbox under **Appliation visibility**

Once you have that setup, you can look at Okta's [React Native OpenID Connect](https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/react-native/nodejs/express) quickstart to see how you can integrate your React Native application with Okta.

Comment: The end user will  login  via okta where okta dashboard page should display this reactjs natie app. so can i use OpenID Connect. if i am using openid connect in okta to create a new app to configure my app and  if i  have assigned to sample users, but the user cant see the app in there Dashboard page can i know why?? should i use SAML,Oauth2 or can i get it by OpenID Connect